# What Star Frontiers rule(s) can model Rifts' "Invulnerability"?

Tags: conversion, rifts, heroes-unlimited

Our group frequently converts characters from one system to another in the course of our gaming. We are attempting to model the Rifts ability of immunity to physical damage (the specific ability of Invulnerability coupled with a few other immunity powers to cover the corner cases; not the MDC stat) in the Star Frontiers setting. Alpha Dawn and Knight Hawks are both available; perhaps I'm just missing it, but I don't see anything yet that would fit.

Is there an existing rule or characteristic that I can use from Star Frontiers as an equivalent for the power **Invulnerability** from Rifts? Any official sourcebook is fine. Also willing to consider third party material such as the StarFrontier.com group or Frontier Explorer.

(*This power originates from **Heroes Unlimited** and is brought into Rifts via the **Rifts Conversion Book**.*)

Comment: Which *Rifts* creature are you converting? Also, what resources are available in your *Star Frontiers* game? That is, given the small amount of resources ever published for *Star Frontiers* (like, less than 20 books total, 12 of them adventures, 3 of them screens and sheets, and 1 a tactical board game), do you include things like issues of [*Star Frontiersman*](http://starfrontiersman.com/magazines.php) among your "official" material? (I mean, really, there's just not a lot to draw from!)

Comment: Hmm, Star Frontiersman, while an excellent resource that I use, is not technically official - though, now that you mention it, I'd be willing to look at anything from there too. The ability in question is complete immunity to physical damage.

Comment: So I can brush up on what the text says, what *Rifts* book is that ability from?

Comment: Valid question; I'll have to ask the player for the character sheet to make sure. It has been a while since I approved it and thereby last looked at it, and will have to check again. Please allow me some time to track it down.

Comment: Edited question with the details of the specific power.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an official rule in Star Frontiers related to that anywhere.

I'm not familiar with Rifts at all so I don't know exactly what is being translated but a few options come to mind:

1) If it is just "the character doesn't take damage from any physical attack", then you could just say that any weapon for which an inertia screen or skiensuit is the defense does no damage.

2) if the ability sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, then you could add an Current STA check (or full STA ability check) any time they would take damage to see if it gets through or not.

3) If it is just a reduction in the amount of damage taken, then you could just assign a numeric value to it and have that subtracted off any damage roll.

4) Or you could treat it just like the inertia screens and skiensuits and say that half damage is blocked and the rest gets through.

Comment: Excellent options. I will wait a few days or so, for others to have a chance. Thank you.